# How to get filtered view to work in an entity SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to build an SSRS report to be put in Dynamics CRM and run from a record in the Account entity.  My initial query to pull the data is pretty simple, but the functionality of the SSRS report and filtered view aren't working as expected.  I'm using the custom report data source from the CRM data source folder, so I know that's not the issue ([see here](http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2014/06/crm-2011crm-2013-filtered-view-return-nodata.html)).

Here's my query (which is very basic):

`SELECT Name
      ,Address1_Line1
      ,Address1_Line2
      ,Address1_City
      ,Address1_StateOrProvince
      ,Address1_PostalCode
      ,kore_salespersonidName
      ,kore_coordinatoridName
      ,client_FulfillmentContactName
      ,OpenDeals
      ,OpenRevenue
      ,client_ActivationBalance
      ,client_SponsorLevel
      ,client_PreviousSeasonSpend
      ,client_CurrentSeasonSpend
      ,Description
      ,kore_industryidName
FROM FilteredAccount AS CRMAF_FilteredAccount`

I've also tried to use a another one as a filter for the report using a where clause on the end of the first query, but that just returns a random list of results as well.

Here's the one I've used for the filter:

`SELECT CRMAF_FilteredAccount.AccountId
,CRMAF_FilteredAccount.Name
FROM FilteredAccount as CRMAF_FilteredAccount
WHERE CRMAF_FilteredAccount.statecode = 0`

This is a similar issue I have, but no resolution: [Similar issue.](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a310f1f5-0d00-46e5-b3ab-bf732cc1d033/how-to-create-a-context-sensitive-ssrs-report-with-multiple-datasets?forum=crm)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was just a bug with CRM.  If you originally upload the report and don't specify in the "Display In" that it needs to be in "Forms for related record types" then it doesn't look like it'll change even if you change that value and the report will always run for all records.  I found this [link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/143557) where it suggested that I delete the report and reupload it, which solved the issue.